# Spring Boot JDBCTemplate with MySQL and Maria DB Commit and Rollback Issue

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mariadb, jdbctemplate

I'm using the Spring Boot framework with JDBCTemplate for database access. I use Transactional annotation to enforce transactions for DB calls.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = IllegalStateException.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

With Maria DB, I can see below logs the sequence of transactions and my Transaction rollbacks, and nothing gets committed.

```
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Creating new transaction with name [Test]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-java.lang.IllegalStateException
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Acquired Connection [HikariProxyConnection@368558459 wrapping org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@3e839aa3] for JDBC transaction
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL statement [INSERT INTO test (Col1,Col2) values(1,'ABC')]
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Initiating transaction rollback
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@368558459 wrapping org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@3e839aa3]
o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Releasing JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@368558459 wrapping org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@3e839aa3] after transaction
```

However, with MySQl 5.1 database I can see in logs that transaction is rolled back, but DB changes are still committed.

In Debug mode, I was able to see the moment JDBC template.execute call happens records get committed and trscationManager get a notification for rollback as I am throwing explicit Checked Exception and defining.

Why rollback is not happening with MySQL but happens in MariaDB?

**My SQL LOG Trail**

```
DataSourceTransactionManager     : Creating new transaction with name [TEST]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'jdbcDataSourceTransactionManager'

DataSourceTransactionManager  : Acquired Connection [HikariProxyConnection@436329238 wrapping 
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2b464384] for JDBC transaction
JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update

JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO TEST (dataNetwork,start, end, type, directory, rank) values(?, ?, ?,?,?,?)]

DataSourceTransactionManager     : Initiating transaction rollback

DataSourceTransactionManager     : Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@436329238 wrapping 

com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2b464384]
DataSourceTransactionManager     : Releasing JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@436329238 wrapping 

com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2b464384] after transaction
DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: To Test Roll Back
```

***Service Method Code:***

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "jdbcDataSourceTransactionManager")
public void copyDataNetwork(WorkingFolderCopyRequest workingFolderCopyRequest,
      DataNetworkTransaction transaction) throws RuntimeException {
    dataNetoworkDao.copy(DataNetworkTables.DATA_NETWORK.getTableName(),
       DataNetworkTables.DATA_NETWORK.getColumnName(),
        workingFolderCopyRequest.getSource(), 
 workingFolderCopyRequest.getDestination());

    throw new RuntimeException("To Test Roll Back");
}
```

***DataNetworkDAO***

```
@Repository
public class DataNetworkDAO  {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public DataNetworkDaoImpl(@Qualifier("ooretaDataSource")DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void copy(String tableName, String dataNetworkColumn, String oldNetworkName, String newNetworkName) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST (dataNetwork,start, end, type, directory, rank) values(:dataNetwork, :start, :end,:type,:directory,:rank)";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("dataNetwork", "WF20");
        params.put("start", "2");
        params.put("end", "");
        params.put("type", "T");
        params.put("directory", "Temp");
        params.put("rank", 0);

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params);
        
    }
}
```

**DataSource Config**

HikariPool-2 - configuration:
allowPoolSuspension.............false
autoCommit......................false
HikariPool-2 - Starting...
HikariPool-2 - Added connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@608eb42e
HikariPool-2 - Start completed.

o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : Database ->
name : MySQL version : 5.1.73-community major : 5  minor : 1

o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : Driver ->
name : MySQL Connector Java  version : mysql-connector-java-5.1.25
( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )  major : 5    minor : 1

Comment: Add the database driver used for each DB - MariaDB and MySQL.

Comment: <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc<artifactId>mariadb-java-client<version>2.1.2
<groupId>mysql<artifactId>mysql-connector-java<version>5.1.49

Comment: @ShankarPS Any Idea why it is behaving in this way?

Comment: During Debug I observed jdbacTemaplate.execute call adds the record in the DB which I am able to query via workbench, next logline is rollback but records still persists.

Comment: Please add the following. 1. log trace for MySQL. 2. the source code of the method

Comment: @ShankarPS I have updated my question with My SQL Details and snippet of calling to called cod with data source config in debug mode for Hikari Pool. showing only which can helo to tell what is Db environment and autoCommit is false.

Answer (score 3):

After all struggles, I found the reason. Programmer Happiness I got in this COVID time.

MySql has 2 DB Engines MyISAM and InnoDB. This legacy DB is having all the tables with the MyISAM engine. MyISAM engine doesn't support transactions. You can't rollback.

If we use SHOW TABLE STATUS; then it will show which table is with which engine type and then we need to Alter the table engine as below to get transactional support.

ALTER TABLE <<table_name>> ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

***And finally, rollback worked like a charm.***

**Link to read more:**

[http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/using-rollback-with-myisam-2010-03-31/#:~:text=The%20MySQL%20default%20storage%20engine,at%20the%20delta%20over%20time](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/using-rollback-with-myisam-2010-03-31/#:%7E:text=The%20MySQL%20default%20storage%20engine,at%20the%20delta%20over%20time).